# Convert single row from table which represents data at year level into 12 rows to represent data at month level

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which provides currency exchange rate details at year level. that is 1 record for each year. I need to convert each row into 12 rows to represent the data at month level. It's like duplicating the single row into 12 rows (for 12 months) and only difference will be in date column which needs to show 12 months.

Example

**Input table**

| Id | date | exchangerate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 1.8 |
| 2 | 2021 | 2.9 |

***Required output***

| Id | date | exchangerate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan-2022 | 1.8 |
| 1 | feb-2022 | 1.8 |
| 1 | mar-2022 | 1.8 |
| . | . | . |
| 1 | dec-2022 | 1.8 |
| 2 | jan-2021 | 2.9 |
| 2 | feb-2021 | 2.9 |
| . | . | . |
| 2 | dec-2021 | 2.9 |

And so on.

I thought of creating a static table with 12 rows for months and cross joining it with my input table but I don't have approval to create a new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a table; you can generate the equivalent using a sub-query or sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause:

```sql
WITH months (month) AS (
  SELECT 'Jan' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Feb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mar' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apr' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'May' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jun' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jul' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aug' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Sep' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Oct' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Nov' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Dec' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT id,
       TO_DATE(month || '-' || "DATE", 'Mon-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English') AS "DATE",
       exchange_rate
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN months m
```

or, you can use a collection:

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t."DATE" || '-01', 'YYYY-MM'), m.COLUMN_VALUE) AS "DATE",
       t.exchange_rate
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)) m
```

or a row-generator:

```sql
WITH months (id, month, "DATE", exchange_rate) AS (
  SELECT id, 1, "DATE", exchange_rate
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, month + 1, "DATE", exchange_rate
  FROM   months
  WHERE  month < 12
)
SELECT id,
       TO_DATE("DATE" || '-' || month, 'YYYY-MM') AS "DATE",
       exchange_rate
FROM   months;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, "DATE", exchange_rate) AS
  SELECT 1, 2022, 1.8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2021, 2.9 FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| ID | DATE | EXCHANGE_RATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 1.8 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 00:00:00 | 1.8 |
| 2 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 2.9 |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 00:00:00 | 2.9 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 2 | 2021-12-01 00:00:00 | 2.9 |

*Note: `DATE` is a reserved word and you should not use it as an identifier; if you do then you need to use a quoted identifier.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RCQehcSq)

Comment: Thank you for your response. the logic works well.

Answer (score 0):

It is about some kind of a row generator; here's one option.

I'm setting date format (so that you'd know `what is what`). Result is displayed in that format; you can switch to `Mon-yyyy` or any other format, if you want - either at session level, or by applying `to_char` function, ... whatever.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Sample data:

```
SQL> with input_table (id, datum, exchangerate) as
  2    (select 1, 2022, 1.8 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 2021, 2.9 from dual
  4    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  select
  6    id,
  7    add_months(trunc(to_date(datum, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'), column_value - 1) datum,
  8    exchangerate
  9  from input_table cross join
 10    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                        connect by level <= 12
 12                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13  order by id, datum;

        ID DATUM      EXCHANGERATE
---------- ---------- ------------
         1 01.01.2022          1,8
         1 01.02.2022          1,8
         1 01.03.2022          1,8
         1 01.04.2022          1,8
         1 01.05.2022          1,8
         1 01.06.2022          1,8
         1 01.07.2022          1,8
         1 01.08.2022          1,8
         1 01.09.2022          1,8
         1 01.10.2022          1,8
         1 01.11.2022          1,8
         1 01.12.2022          1,8
         2 01.01.2021          2,9
         2 01.02.2021          2,9
         2 01.03.2021          2,9
         2 01.04.2021          2,9
         2 01.05.2021          2,9
         2 01.06.2021          2,9
         2 01.07.2021          2,9
         2 01.08.2021          2,9
         2 01.09.2021          2,9
         2 01.10.2021          2,9
         2 01.11.2021          2,9
         2 01.12.2021          2,9

24 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, even this logic works well as per the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use LEVEL ... CONNECT BY as a generator with ADD_MONTHS() function like :

```sql
WITH         -- Sample data
    tbl AS
      (
          Select 1 "ID", 2022 "A_DATE",  1.8 "EXCHANGE_RATE" From Dual Union All
          Select 2,      2021,           2.9                 From Dual
      )
--
--  Main SQL
Select      ID,
            To_Char(ADD_MONTHS(To_Date('01.01.' || t.A_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy'), (l.LVL-1) ), 'Mon-yyyy') "MONTHS", 
            EXCHANGE_RATE
From        tbl t
Inner Join  ( Select LEVEL "LVL" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 12) l ON(1 = 1)
Order By    t.ID, l.LVL
--
-- R e s u l t :
        ID MONTHS            EXCHANGE_RATE
---------- ----------------- -------------
         1 Jan-2022                    1.8
         1 Feb-2022                    1.8
         1 Mar-2022                    1.8
         1 Apr-2022                    1.8
        ..    ...         ....        ....
         1 Nov-2022                    1.8
         1 Dec-2022                    1.8
        -- 
         2 Jan-2021                    2.9
         2 Feb-2021                    2.9
         2 Mar-2021                    2.9
        ..    ...         ....        ....
         2 Nov-2021                    2.9
         2 Dec-2021                    2.9
```

Comment: Hi, The logic is working perfectly but i am getting error for last statement order by  l.LVL error says ORA-01791 not a selected expression. I need to sort it by mon-yyy

Comment: @Pranali  --> Select * From ( current sql code in brackets ) Order By  ID, To_Date(MONTHS, 'Mon-yyyy')  - or any other order by clause